# How to find certain Cyrillic string with regex

Tags: php, regex

For example:

```
{% if Вид != '' %}<b>Вид:</b> {{ Вид | raw}}<br>{% endif %}
{% if Сертификат_за_безопасност != '' %}<b>Сертификат за безопасност:</b> {{ Сертификат_за_безопасност | raw}}<br>{% endif %}
```

Here I want to find if there is actually pattern

```
preg_match("/{% if {Cyrillic} != '' %}/i", $features)
```

I am trying with this one but got `0` as result

Comment: Maybe just make `\w` Unicode-aware? `'/{% if \w+ != '' %}/iu'`

Comment: At any rate, you have a typo here, as Unicode property classes have a `\p{class_name}` syntax.

Answer (score -2):

to find Cyrillic you can use expression `[а-яА-Я]+`
in your case it could looks like `{% if [а-яА-Я]+ != '' %}`

Comment: `[а-яА-Я]` is not matching all Cyrillic chars. It is not even matching all Russian letters.

Comment: yes, i forget about ёЁ


`<?php

$str = "{% if Вид != '' %}<b>Вид:</b> {{ Вид | raw}}<br>{% endif %}
{% if Сертификат_за_безопасност != '' %}<b>Сертификат за безопасност:</b> {{ Сертификат_за_безопасност | raw}}<br>{% endif %}";

preg_match("/{% if [а-яА-ЯёЁ]+ != '' %}/mui", $str, $result);
print_r($result);`


[link]http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25e5ad4e401853229d0affad8c50517d0d1f06a9

Comment: I am not sure this is still what OP wants. It looks to be Bulgarian here, and they have got no `ё` there. The thing is that this character class alone is not likely to help.